# Living in a nuclear bunker

Tags: internal-consistency, radiation

Life on Earth has been annihilated because of a nuclear war. Everything above ground has far too much radiation to be hospitable. How can life go on?

Living in a bunker would have the following basic needs:

- food
- water
- energy

**Food** can be obtained by farming in the bunker.

**Water** is a more difficult question. You could store up water, but because humans need around 60 gal. per year, we're talking about a tank with thousands of gallons of water to sustain only three people for half a century. (This doesn't take into account showering or cleaning either). Drawing water from outside would also be problematic because it would be irradiated.

**Energy** is only somewhat of a problem. If someone figured out how to harness energy from the radiation outside, then it would be trivial to power the bunker.

So my question is, **how can drinkable water be obtained during globally high levels of radiation?**

Comment: Hello! I can see you're pretty new to our site, so I'm going to explain why you're getting close votes only minutes after posting the question. You see, on WB SE we typically help users refine ideas for their own universes and stories. However, we expect that user to give us some information to go on, and to do some research. Collating many questions into a single post like you're doing is very broad. Typically you should only ask a single pointed question per post. Also, a lot of your questions are purely opinion based. Take #3 for example. The answer is ***maybe***. Who knows, really?

Comment: Here's some good reading regarding WB SE: [Is WB a what-if site](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/is-worldbuilding-a-what-if-site?rq=1) | [Risk Factors](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3206/worldbuilding-scope-risk-factors?cb=1) I suggest taking a look and rephrasing your question. Also, some of the information you seek can be very easily Googled. For example, can radiation seep into water/food? Yes, of course. You could probably get this off of wikipedia, but there are dozens of good articles on the subject.

Comment: For example, if you were to ask: **Taking the Fallout series (link to wiki) as a baseline, How long would it take the radiation to dissipate to survivable levels? Would above-ground settlements be plausible after only a century or two?** That right there is probably an on-scope WB question. You could then request further details and clarifications in other questions. You could also join us WB chat and start a conversation about it :-)   (check the dropdown in the top left, next to the log-out button)

Comment: You didn't waste any time. Good edit! Close vote retracted

Comment: I think the answer is extremely obvious. Use geothermal energy for power; a well for water (because water deep underground shouldn't be irradiated), and don't waste any water, re-use it _all_ and have lots of filters; and as you said grow food underground. The main problem I see would be the nutrients necessary for hydroponics.

Comment: This is an Old US DOD manual entitled Nuclear War Survival Skills. it has 9 pages on the topic.
https://ia800501.us.archive.org/35/items/NuclearWarSurvivalSkills_201405/nwss.pdf

@JBH This might be worth considering for the Resources List?

Answer (score 5):

Where you built your bunker, and how badly affected your area is, are going to be key factors in all this.

Generally speaking, your bunker is going to require insanely efficient air and water recycling systems. Every drop of moisture should be captured, filtered, and reused. This will mean that those 60 gallons/year might last you quite a while.

However, you also need water for hydroponics ("farming" in the bunker), cooling, etc. At some point or another, you will have to draw more water from the outside. And if your bunker isn't tapped into some local water supply (an underground spring, or even the local water table) you're in trouble (you may have to organize expeditions to the surface, pump some in using hoses, etc - very messy. Better if you design your bunker with this in mind, to begin with).

The water you draw in is probably going to be "irradiated". At least that's what us laymen would say. Actually, water can't be irradiated - it can, however, have irradiated particles suspended in it. This means you ***can filter them out***. There are articles out there on how to DIY, so I think it's fairly well-established that it's possible.

Power is also not a problem, as you would be able to drill down and set up a geothermal plant.

Comment: Strictly speaking water can be irradiated though this is not going to happen to any significant degree simply from fallout to be irradiated by neutron capture would require direct exposure to a neutron source for some time such as a nuclear reactor. The radioactive isotopes of O are very unstable with halflifes being on the order of minutes however the halflife of Hydrogen-3 (Tritium) is around 12 years so neutron capture could make the water itself slightly radioactive but since free neutrons are only flying about during fission and not simply the decay it's correct in this context.

Answer (score 2):

**Food**

I think, food would be much harder as you think. The current, not really overfeed humanity needs around 0.1 - 1 square kilometer to feed a single human. Now compare it to the cost of digging underground train tunnels. Even if you can somehow solve the problem of the tremendous light need.

On my opinion, food is essentially unsolvable problem by the current technology in underground farming.

**Water**

Water is from Hydrogen and Oxigen. Fortunately, all of the instabile isotopes of oxygen decays very fast (in decays in days). Hydrogen has only a single dangerous isotope, it is the Tritium. It has a half life of around 12 years. Fortunately, nuclear explosions create them only in negligible quantity (but, for example, in the safety protocols of nuclear reactors it is an important issue).

So, "radioactive water" would mean only non-radioactive water with radioactive contamination. It can be simply eliminated with distillation, filtering, etc.

**Energy**

The radiation contains very small energy compared to its damage. The thermal energy of the radiation which is enough to kill a human, wouldn't be enough to boil a cup of coffee. Harnessing energy from the radiation outside would be infeasible.

But, I think, energy can be solved most easily. Having underground nuclear reactors - or using the already available water and nuclear reactors on the surface - could be enough. Or the remaining surface reactors could be used by the survivors, and their voltage could be lead into the bunker.

---

What could work:

1. The current nuclear weaponry of the global powers don't target to exterminate the life on the Earth. They are constructed to make the other powers incapable to fight. So, their goal is not to sterilize, their goal is to mechanically destruct the rockets, factories, cities, military bases and government centers of the enemy. Thus, firing all of the currently existing nuclear rockets would kill a lot of people, but the Earth would survive it with minor problems. On the longterm, it would be even a positive result from an ecological view (compare the well developed fauna around the abandoned Chernobyl nucler plant - for the wild animals, it is *much* better to live in the vicinity of Chernobyl, as in the vicinity of New York). We, humans, with our pesticides, weapons, roads, deforestation, are much more dangerous to the ecosystem as our nuclear weapons.

Or course there are nuclear weapons which *[could](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_bomb)* goal to sterilize the Earth and it would be possible to construct them in the needed quantity, but they are only plans. Not because the major global powers are so good boys, but because their goal is not to sterilize the Earth, but to destroy the other.

2. Majority of the nuclear radiation would be gone in some years. There are around 4-500 nuclear isotopoes, around 2/3 of them is instabile (i.e. radioactive). Most of them decays very fast, and so they are a no-issue on the longterm. Many of them decays *very* long (in centuries or more). They are not really radioactive. And many of them won't be produced in nuclear explosions.

There is only around 5 really problematic isotopes.

For example, around the Chernobyl plant is there still dangerous radiation, but this danger means only that living there, you would have a significant chance to get cancer in some decades.

If the whole surface of the Earth would be the same, our life expectations would be much worse for some generations, but the humanity would survive it.

Answer (score 0):

### There are many solutions

The Immediate solution I thought of is to build it underwater in the first place, primarily in the Marianas Trench, where there is plenty of water, but that would require a very effective water purifier. A quick google search later and I found [this website.](http://undergroundbombshelter.com/)

It agreed with my thoughts that a wise choice when planning your water storage is to have at least one water treatment option on hand. It may be necessary to venture out of the shelter for more water (or if underwater, open a water chamber). If you have to stay for an extended period of time in any shelter with even a large amount of stored clean water, your water may become contaminated and require treatment. If there is any question about the potability of your water, it’s safest to treat it first. Luckily you have several options available for emergency water treatment, including:

- Boiling- Boiling is one of the easiest and most reliable ways of rendering your water safe to drink. If your shelter includes a means of cooking, you can boil water for 3-5 minutes to kill pathogens. Boiling releases a great deal of steam, so if you choose boiling as your method of purification then you want to have a steam distillation system in place. This can be done very easily and cheaply in several different ways- for example, a length of copper pipe directing the steam from a boiling kettle to a wide-mouthed jar or other container (not plastic). The result will be clear, clean distilled water that is safe for drinking.
- Hand Pump Filtration- These are small, portable water filters typically intended for backpacking and outdoor adventures. While compact and easy to store with your disaster supply kit, they can be expensive and are really only intended for use by a single individual. Using a manual pump to filter multiple gallons of water every day for an entire family could be extremely difficult and time-consuming. It is, however, a better choice than no treatment at all.
- Chemical Filtration- Water purification tablets can be effective against bacteria, but may not eliminate other contaminants such as protozoa. You can purchase the tablets from an outdoor supply store, or you can choose to simply store iodine or chlorine. In a pinch, household chlorine bleach can be used at 1/8 tsp (8 drops) per gallon. Chemical filtration is likely to affect the color and flavor of the water.
- Ultraviolet Light- A device that uses UV light to deactivate bacteria/protozoa in the water is another option for small amounts of water. UV light will not protect against possible viruses in the water. Unlike chemical filtration, UV light will not alter the flavor or color of the water, because it simply inactivates any pathogens present in the water and renders them harmless.

Comment: I think defense against bacteria is not a problem here, the problem is the radioactive elements in the water.

Answer (score 0):

You want all the water you can get - for radiation shielding. [Nasa is looking at it](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn23230-mars-trip-to-use-astronaut-poo-as-radiation-shield/). Build your shelter *inside* a great big cistern or a series of tanks, maybe with double walls with an outer layer shielding an inner layer. As long as there's no *fallout* contaminating your water you ought to be fine. The CDC's decontamination protocols seem more concerned with radioactive dust than [water contamination anyway](http://emergency.cdc.gov/radiation/selfdecon_wash.asp).

If you water wasn't radioactive to start with you should be fine. (as an aside, human waste makes good shielding too. So if your outer layer of defensive water isn't radioactive, you could use that to store your "post consumer food", assuming you arn't using it as manure.

You could also reclaim waste water (directly, through various filtration methods, or indirectly by use of it as humanure or as nutrients for hydrophonics).  This could be through filteration,distillation, condensing ambient water vapor or other means. Just treat the whole structure like a stillsuit.

Water's also a great way to *store* energy- you could possibly use a cycle or other pump to pump up water, and use it to turn a small generator for small sustained power needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that as the radiation comes from speciffic molecules from the radioactive materials that special nanofilters only large enough to allow the water to pass through may suffice. 
there are already items of this nature in existance with aperently solid bricks which will allow water to pass through seemingly uninhibited.

As for showering the solution could be much simpler with a filtration to reduce particles of dirt and dead skin the same water could in theory be recycled for a substantial amount of time.especially if it were chemically treated as city water is today.

Comment: If the radiation were particles you could filter it.  Dissolved radioactives will be much harder to remove, though.  Reverse osmosis will get some but it's not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Improvised Filter]

### Clay and sand filters

As of 1987, the US DOD recommended a clay and sand filter to filter out radioactive isotopes from water. They could be engineered or improvised.
See [Nuclear War Survival Skills](https://ia800501.us.archive.org/35/items/NuclearWarSurvivalSkills_201405/nwss.pdf), chapter 8 for a full discussion of how to ensure clean water.
It is more fuel efficient than boiling based solutions.

### Disinfection

NWSS says that biological contamination is more likely to be dangerous than fallout contamination in many areas. Conventional disinfection using filtration or chlorine is advisable.

### Reverse osmosis

The effectiveness of RO is proportional to (hydrated) ion size. Uranium is either going to be in the form of particulates (in which case conventional filters will remove it), or salts (in which case RO would be very effective).

Comment: Why did you answer this question...? It's almost seven years old.

Comment: Bother, missed the date. It came up on the home page. I normally check. Never mind!

Answer (score 0):

It's energy-intensive but you can simply draw in outside water and purify it with distillation.  That will remove almost everything that could be radioactive (it will miss tritium but that's not going to be a big factor.)

Your limiting factor is energy, not water.